# Any free/affordable alternatives to Polldaddy?

Tags: php, looking-for-a-script, alternative, surveys

I'm looking for a free/cheap embeddable poll that I can just stuff in an iframe - the page I've been tasked to maintain has been created in iWeb, which does not generate anything but the final markup of the page. Polldaddy seems nice, but if you get over 100 responses in a month you're instantly in the $200/year bracket. Are there any services that are free/cheaper that will do the same basic thing?

What about software I can host myself? I'm willing to toss up a PHP script so long as I can embed it in iWeb's iframe.

Comment: For whatever it's worth, being responsible for, maintaining, etc. whatever self-installed script you find is probably going to cost more than $200/yr. Not explicitly invoicing it doesn't negate the time spent.

Answer (score 2):

You can [create a poll with a Google Docs Form & embed it](http://googledocs.blogspot.com/2008/05/embed-your-forms.html) in your website.

[Zoho Polls](http://zohopolls.com/) is also free & embeddable.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, and sorry it's taken so long for me to reply. I had toyed with the idea of using Google docs, but I couldn't figure out how to get it to display the results of the poll after the user voted. Is there a way to do that? Also thanks for the tip about Zoho, I'm looking it it.

Answer (score 1):

After some searching I've found [Micropoll](http://www.micropoll.com/) which seems pretty good and seems to be free.

Comment: Is there some kind of cap or charge involved with that one? They have to make money somehow..

Comment: @Tim I would assume they have a few ads

Answer (score 0):

Try this [poll widget](http://pollwidget.org). Very customizable and free as per your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on mvark's answer and the follow up question,

You can **embed a Google spreadsheet** ...hint... (the result of the poll spreadsheet).
It's a trivial thing to do (Google it) and compliments mvark's good answer.

Even better yet, You can query or use formulas on the results from another sheet and customize your embeded results to your liking. 
Ex: Let people vote as much as they want but only provide unique IP results in your embeded results.